# oauth2 and csrf attck

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, csrf

I'm currently working on oauth2 implementation and i wonder about CSRF attack.

I so very good explanation : in this scheme https://image.slidesharecdn.com/owasp-nulloauth2-160803124628/95/oauth-20-security-considerations-11-638.jpg?cb=1470228518 or this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_xrhWLqX1j0 but i dont understand the goal.

At the end my account will have access to the attacker account, i cant get data from it but not the reverse. Am I right ? What is the benefit for the attacker to do this ?

Thank's for your answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several other answers (ex:- [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52459476/does-oauth-state-mitigate-any-genuinely-dangerous-attacks/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46844285/difference-between-oauth-2-0-state-and-openid-nonce-parameter-why-state-cou)) explaining the background of state and how it avoid csrf.

Best thing is to refer what is given by specification creators. [RFC6810](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819) - OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations contains many threats and counter measurements for OAuth 2.0. In that [Threat: CSRF Attack against redirect-uri](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819#section-4.4.1.8) gives a solid overview on the threat. Following is an extract,

> An attacker could authorize an authorization "code" to
> their own protected resources on an authorization server.  He then
> aborts the redirect flow back to the client on his device and tricks
> the victim into executing the redirect back to the client.  The
> client receives the redirect, fetches the token(s) from the
> authorization server, and associates the victim's client session with
> the resources accessible using the token.

Now client has tokens which belongs to attacker. No, attacker won't be able to access anything that belongs to client in resource server. But if client perform a storing operation (ex :- Document create), this will be sent to malicious party. Now malicious party get access rights to those freshly created resource. This is highlighted as below,

> The
> effective impact depends on the type of resource accessed.  For
> example, the user may upload private items to an attacker's
> resources.  Or, when using OAuth in 3rd-party login scenarios, the
> user may associate his client account with the attacker's identity at
> the external Identity Provider.  In this way, the attacker could
> easily access the victim's data at the client by logging in from
> another device with his credentials at the external Identity
> Provider.

**So basically threat is associated with fresh data created at resource server**.